# How to put all the textfields into an array?

Tags: java, javafx

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML private TextField buffer0;
    @FXML private TextField buffer1;
    @FXML private TextField buffer2;
    @FXML private TextField buffer3;
    @FXML private TextField buffer4;
    private TextField[] bufferFields;
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        bufferFields = new TextField[5];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend a `List<TextField>` but you can do it just like any array.

```
butterFields = new TextField[]{ buffer0, buffer1, buffer2, buffer3, buffer4};
```

Comment: `buffer`, not `butter`

Comment: It's almost dinner time here.